# How can I disable react native stack navigator on specific screens?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

In my React-Native application I am using a stack navigator to navigate between the login screen and the home screen. However, the problem is that when I go to the home screen I want to switch to tab navigation and I don't want the user to have the capability to hit the back arrow and go back to the login screen. So how can I disable the stack navigator completely on the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Create a stack navigator function and only store the home screen like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

    import LoginScreen from 'LoginScreen';


    export const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
   

     {
           LoginScreen:{
              screen: LoginScreen
          }
        },
    
        {
            initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen'
        }
```

)

Do the same for tab navigator but use home screen instead and use createTabNavigator. Make sure to install the packages.